# How to save each iterating Statsmodel as a file to be used later?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, regression, statsmodels

I have the following table generated:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Generate 'random' data
np.random.seed(0)
X = 2.5 * np.random.randn(10) + 1.5
res = 0.5 * np.random.randn(10)
y = 2 + 0.3 * X + res
Name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

# Create pandas dataframe to store our X and y values
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': Name,
     'X': X,
     'y': y})

# Show the dataframe
df
```

Resulting in the following table:

| Name | X | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5.910131 | 3.845061 |
| B | 2.500393 | 3.477255 |
| C | 3.946845 | 3.564572 |
| D | 7.102233 | 4.191507 |
| E | 6.168895 | 4.072600 |
| F | -0.943195 | 1.883879 |
| G | 3.875221 | 3.909606 |
| H | 1.121607 | 2.233903 |
| I | 1.241953 | 2.529120 |
| J | 2.526496 | 2.330901 |

The the following code iterates to exludes one row at a time, and builds a set of regression plots:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
# Initialise and fit linear regression model using `statsmodels`

for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
    # dataframe with all rows except for one
    df_reduced = df[~(df.index == row_index)]
    model = smf.ols('X ~ y', data=df_reduced)
    model = model.fit()
    intercept, slope = model.params
    print(model.summary())

    y1 = intercept + slope * df_reduced.y.min()
    y2 = intercept + slope * df_reduced.y.max()
    plt.plot([df_reduced.y.min(), df_reduced.y.max()], [y1, y2], label=row.Name, color='red')
    plt.scatter(df_reduced.y, df_reduced.X)
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig(f"All except {row.Name} analogue.pdf")
    plt.show()
```

The question is, how can I save each of the models that are being generated as a file that can be used later ? In this present example, there should be at least 9 regression models being generated. I would like to have them each as a file that can be identified with a name as well.

Second question is, how can I add a space in between each of the model summary and plots in the visual generations of matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this: `model.save(f"model_{row_index}.pkl")` in you loop

Comment: If you want to load: import statsmodels.api as sm       model = sm.load("model_9.pkl")

Comment: Thanks, do you have a method to name each of the model saved ? I may need to use 'row.Name' instead of 'row_index'

Comment: Yes of course just use this instead: model.save(f"model_{row.Name}.pkl")

Comment: ?? What space? Now your plots individual. You mean in the screen? just add several     print() after plt.show()

Comment: Really sorry just one more thing - do you think it will be possible to ensure that all of the names of the scatter plots can be produced ? For example, could I show that each of the blue scatter dot is either A, B, C, D, E and etc with its values ? Especially since all this data is already available on the table ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252939/discussion-between-dinesh-and-theengineerprogrammer).

Answer (score 1):

Storing the trained models:
Assuming you have some naming procedure available for each model file mf, you can store a model using pickle.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pickle

# Train your model
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

# Save the model to a file
with open('model.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)

# Load the model from the file
with open('model.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    loaded_model = pickle.load(f)

print(loaded_model.summary())
```

gives the following output.

```
                                     OLS Regression Results                                
=======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared (uncentered):                   0.525
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared (uncentered):              0.472
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                              9.931
Date:                Mon, 03 Apr 2023   Prob (F-statistic):                      0.0117
Time:                        12:42:57   Log-Likelihood:                         -20.560
No. Observations:                  10   AIC:                                      43.12
Df Residuals:                       9   BIC:                                      43.42
Df Model:                           1                                                  
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                                  
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             0.8743      0.277      3.151      0.012       0.247       1.502
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        1.291   Durbin-Watson:                   0.989
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.524   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.937
Skew:                           0.637   Prob(JB):                        0.626
Kurtosis:                       2.209   Cond. No.                         1.00
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] R² is computed without centering (uncentered) since the model does not contain a constant.
[2] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Notice that the model import is a bit different from yours for simplification purposes. You should be able to store and load your model in the same manner however.

I am not entirely sure I understand your questions regarding spacing of the outputs and plots correctly.

Spacing the summaries:
Just add emtpy print() statements maybe?

Spacing the plots:
You are generating entirely new plots every time, hence I do not understand the question. Feel free to give additional info and I will get back to you.